# Gem libxml-ruby (1.1.4) installs but fails on runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, osx-mavericks, libxml2

I'm trying to run one quite old Rails application on Mavericks where one of the requirements are:
- Ruby ree-1.8.7-2009.10
- Rails 3.0.0
- libxml-ruby 1.1.4 (that's the latest version compatible with the rest of the gems.

I have latest libxml2 package installed. It's version from Homebrew (2.9.1).

To install this gem I used following command:

```
$ CC=gcc-4.2 gem install libxml-ruby -v '1.1.4'
```

Output suggested success:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed libxml-ruby-1.1.4
1 gem installed
```

though when I try run some rake task, i.e. creating database
    bundle exec rake db:create

I get following error:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:create                                                                                               [ree-1.8.7-2009.10@mygemset]
rake aborted!
dlsym(0x7ffa2d83bbe0, Init_libxml_ruby): symbol not found - /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2009.10@mygemset/gems/libxml-ruby-1.1.4/lib/libxml_ruby.bundle
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2009.10@mygemset/gems/libxml-ruby-1.1.4/lib/libxml_ruby.bundle
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2009.10@mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2009.10@mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2009.10@mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:597:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2009.10@mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2009.10@mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2009.10@mygemset/gems/libxml-ruby-1.1.4/lib/libxml.rb:9
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2009.10@mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2009.10@mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2009.10@mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2009.10@mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:597:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2009.10@mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2009.10@mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
/Users/myuser/Developer/my-project/vendor/private_gems/restful_authentication-1.4.9/lib/sso/sso.rb:3
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2009.10@mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2009.10@mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2009.10@mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2009.10@mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:597:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2009.10@mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2009.10@mygemset/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
/Users/myuser/Developer/my-project/vendor/private_gems/restful_authentication-1.4.9/lib/restful_sso_authentication.rb:2
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2009.10@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2009.10@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2009.10@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2009.10@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2009.10@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2009.10@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2009.10@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
/Users/myuser/Developer/my-project/config/application.rb:5
/Users/myuser/Developer/my-project/Rakefile:6:in `require'
/Users/myuser/Developer/my-project/Rakefile:6
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have tried numerous approaches that can be found on Internet (the most relevant examples concerned problems with installing Nokogiri and similar errors where listed) and none of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my way to install Rubies on variety of Mac OSes for long long time. For me, there were any no problems with any library or gem. For example more complex *Nokogiri* gem builds and works like a charm.

**Check XCode version**

```
xcodebuild -version
xcode-select --install
```

**Install Homebrew** as per it's documentation

**Install prerequisites**

```
brew doctor; # Just do what it wants!
brew update;
brew upgrade; # Watch out! for existing bottles
brew install libtool libxml2 libxslt openssl sqlite libyaml;
brew install autoconf automake apple-gcc42;
brew cleanup; # Watch out! for existing bottles
brew tap homebrew/dupes; # Watch out! for existing bottles
```

**Install RVM**

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable # Latest stable
rvm get latest
rvm reload # :)
rvm autolibs enable
rvm requirements
```

**Install Ruby**

```
rvm install 2.1 --disable-binary
```

Comment: I'd add one small line to this. I'd uninstall the libraries and then installing them all over.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a previous version break the native loading or your libxml2 is too recent and don't fit the gem implementation.

- first uninstall all previous gems (gemset, system)
- then reinstall the gem

https://gist.github.com/unixcharles/1226596 ?